# How do animals perform detailed active camouflage?

Tags: pigmentation

We often see videos of octopuses and chameleons changing their color to suit their surroundings. If it was a simple color change from white to red, it'd be understandable, but some of these animals can change colors while incorporating a lot of detail.

How do they process so much information and mimic it. Is this a subconscious action, or do they actually draw a picture in their head and then 'print' it on their bodies? Does this ability come from birth or does it get better over time?

Answer (score 1):

Some of it is voluntary and some involuntary and is detailed in this [book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=kYEqWKFuspkC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=Is%20the%20color%20change%20of%20chameleon-like%20creatures,%20voluntary%20or%20involuntary?&source=bl&ots=sqxUyzAPnO&sig=cFrS4lgzGFdAK6mmp6DiDfIPEbg&hl=el&ei=RKImSoXyJ4yK_QaTj-ztBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). Chameleons have [chromatophores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatophore) (pigment containing light reflecting organelles in cells) which help in their colour change and many factors like age, health, etc does affect it. And no, they do not form a picture on their head and print it on their bodies.